# NodeJs/ Typescript errorhandler typing

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am using NodeJs/express and Typescript.

at the moment when I do a request, the compiler find understand the type of `(req, res)`, and I do not need to do anything.

```
UserRouter.post('/user/me/avatar', avatar, async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send();
})
```

I am trying to add an errorHandler to my route. when the middlewear throw an error, I would like to execute a function.

I saw that you can do the following

```
UserRouter.post('/user/me/avatar', avatar, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(res)
    res.status(200).send();
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({error : error.message});
})
```

this works, but typescript compiler do not understand the type and throw an error

> Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

I have to write everything with any or I always get a compiler error even if I try to do

```
UserRouter.post('/user/me/avatar', avatar, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(res)
    res.status(200).send();
}, (error: Error, req :Request, res :Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.status(400).send({error : error.message});
})
```

Is there another way to call this error catch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the accordant [option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in your *tsconfig.json* to prevent/suppress these errors:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  ...
}
```

> `--noImplicitAny` Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied any type.

**Edit**

```
UserRouter.post('/user/me/avatar', avatar, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(res)
    res.status(200).send();
}, (error: Error, req :Request, res :Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.status(400).send({error : error.message});
})
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

try {
this.response.send({
code:200,
data: response
})
} catch(error) {

```
    this.response.status(error.Code || 400). send ({
        code:error.code,
        message:error.message
    })

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).